# Can Celestial Aspect: Horns of the Cervidal dismiss without charging?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

**Celestial Aspect Horns of the Cervidal:** (BoED 93)

> Ramlike horns sprout from the target’s head. The target can charge an opponent with its deadly horns. In addition to the normal benefits and hazards of a charge, this tactic allows the creature to make a single gore attack that deals 1d8 points of damage plus 1-1/2 times the target’s Strength modifier. Any summoned or called creature struck by the horns is dismissed instantly.

Our group had a discussion if the dismissal part of the horn only works on a charge or also on a normal horn attack.

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd-level sanctified spell *celestial aspect* [trans] (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 93) is unclear on the effect of the horns of the cervidal. Going back to the source, the description of the cervidal's supernatural ability horn powers says that

> A cervidal can deliver any of several effects by a touch of its horns. The horns can… dismiss (as a [*dismissal*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#dismissal) spell) a summoned, conjured, or extraplanar creature. [This] horn power… can be used at will as a standard action. (*Monster Manual II* 43)

This supports a reading of the horns of the cervidal effect enabling a creature to deliver the *dismissal* effect with even a melee touch attack of its new, sanctified horns.

However, if the horns of the cervidal effect is read as being *automatic* (and it appears it *should* be)—therefore offering the victim *no* saving throw—, this DM would rule that a cervidal horned creature *must* charge and hit the called or summoned creature to activate the *dismissal* effect. A 3rd-level spell—even a sanctified one dealing the caster 1d3 points of Strength damage when the spell ends—shouldn't be able to *easily* end an encounter with a pit fiend! (Especially since the victim's spell resistance may not even apply!)

Which choice will depend on the DM. You're going to have to ask him.

### *You're gone; no save* is no fun

Most likely, though, this DM would take a controversial middle ground: The *dismissal* effect of the horns of the cervidal activate upon the creature with its horns making a melee touch attack *or* attack at the end of a charge, but the touched or charged creature then gets the standard special saving throw against this *dismissal* effect (DC = spell’s save DC – affected creature’s Hit Dice + the *celestial aspect* caster's caster level).

This prevents the aforementioned automatic banishing of high-level threats *and* keeps the spell's power in line with a 3rd-level spell. Although this might disappoint the players initially, such a house rule also prevents PCs from the Prime who are off-plane from being *automatically* returned to a random location on their home plane (80%) or a random location on *another* plane (20%) when they encounter a good caster who just wants them removed from the action.